# SQL: Running total with group by

Tags: sap-ase-16

I have a dataset that has two date columns for each transaction. An invoice date and a charge date. I am trying to do a cumulative or running total of the table in sql.

Data table looks like this:

```
InvoiceDate ChargeDate TransactionID
----------- ---------- -------------
jan/1/2021  jan/1/2021 11111
jan/1/2021  jan/1/2021 55555
jan/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 11111
jan/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 22222
jan/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 33333
jan/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 44444
Feb/1/2021  jan/1/2021 11111
Feb/1/2021  jan/1/2021 22222
Feb/1/2021  jan/1/2021 33333
Feb/1/2021  jan/1/2021 44444
Feb/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 55555
```

I want the **output** in this format:

```
InvoiceDate ChargeDate cumulativeCount
----------- ---------- ---------------
jan/1/2021  jan/1/2021 2
jan/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 5
Feb/1/2021  jan/1/2021 4
Feb/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 5
```

I tried the following code but it doesn't give me a running total. it gives me total of each of the two columns

```
select
    chargeDate,
    InvoiceDate,
    Count(Distinct TransactionID) as CountofIDs
from mytable1
where InvoiceDate<=InvoiceDate
group by ChargeDate, InvoiceDate
```

Comment: Please tag with version of SQL Server - also `InvoiceDate<=InvoiceDate` will always evaluate to true, not sure the purpose.

Comment: tagged the versions i suspect. its the version where OVER function is not supported.

Comment: Do `SELECT @@VERSION` and you should be able to get the exact version, or just leave as 2005 since the only windowing functions were `row_number()`, `rank()`, etc.

Comment: Adaptive Server Enterprise/16.0 SP02 PL04/EBF 26122 SMP/P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux/ase160sp02pl04x/2586/64-bit/FBO/Fri Jun 10 11:33:16 2016

Comment: That's Sybase ASE 16, not SQL Server.  You should be able to use standard windowing functions.

Comment: ahhh... my ignorance. and can you help me what are those standard windowing functions that i'd need here?

Comment: Looking at your desired output and counts, they don't seem to align with the sample data.  1. Should the running count be by `InvoiceDate` and 2. Should the output be `2, 5, 4, 5`?

Comment: You are right, it should be 2, 5, 4, 5 and i've updated the original post.

Comment: fwiw, Sybase ASE does not have support for 'standard windowing functions' so you need to jump through some hoops (eg, self joins)

Comment: sample data shows `jan` (lower case) and `Feb` (upper case); assuming this is not a typo, it appears (to me) these 'date' columns are of type `(var)char` (as opposed to `date` or `datetime`); this could cause an issue with the final results if there happens to be records with the same 'date' but different capitalization for the month **and** the ASE instance is using a case-sensitive sort order (ie, `'feb' != 'Feb'`)

Answer (score 1):

Looking this over, due to the need for a distinct count and the lack of other options in Sybase ASE, you'll have to use a self-join:

```
SELECT
  Tr.InvoiceDt
 ,Tr.ChargeDt
 ,COUNT(DISTINCT PriorTr.TransactionID) AS TransactionCount
FROM
  mytable1 Tr
INNER JOIN
  mytable1 PriorTr
    ON PriorTr.InvoiceDt = Tr.InvoiceDt
        AND PriorTr.ChargeDt <= Tr.ChargeDt
GROUP BY
  Tr.InvoiceDt
 ,Tr.ChargeDt
```

Fiddle here (have to settle for the distant cousin, SQL Server):
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff8e0d/2